# Figure not found in latex

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, includegraphics

Estoy intentado compilar un documento en latex con Texmaker en el que faltan aún varias imagenes. En lugar de dejarme sus huecos vacíos, no llega a compilar. ¿Alguna solución?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a TeX.SE! Please post the code you are trying to compile or it will be impossible to answer your question. Please remember to create a MWE and not add your entire code!

Comment: If you'd post your question in English, there is a wider audience of people here on TeX.SE that could provide help.

Comment: You have to respect the naming conventions. One source of errors are blanks in the file name.